# How to select more than one element while scrapping?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am doing research on news titles and contents reporting on New York Times.

This is what I have written:

```py
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request as req 
import bs4
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import warnings

url = 'https://www.nytimes.com/search?query=ukraine+war'

headers = {
   'User-Agent':
       'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)'
       ' AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'
       ' Chrome/102.0.5005.63 Safari/537.36 Edg/102.0.1245.33'
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html5lib')

title = soup.find_all("h4", "p.css-16nhkrn")

for title in titles:
    title = title.text.strip()
    print(title)

from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

text = title

wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(text)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

I am not sure why `p class = css-16nhkrn` didn't appear. I have tried others but failed.

Comment: are you able to verify that it exists in the document ?

Comment: title = soup.find_all(["h4", "p class=css-16nhkrn"])


I've modified to this but it still the same...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `title = soup.find_all("h4", "p.css-16nhkrn")` to `title = soup.find_all(["h4", "p"])`. This would then allow you to filter the p tags based on the class `css-16nhkrn`, which you can do using regular expressions.

Let me know if this works, or if you need help with regular expressions!

Comment: Sorry, I've tried it out but the output didn't make any changes, only h4 printed out.

Comment: My apologies, the issue was that the find_all function can't look for "p.css-16nhkrn" but just tags. Adding the class confuses the function